# How can I add String from another class in Java?

Tags: java, json, string

I want to add a string from other (`controller`) class into "**JSON class**" which I created but I don't know how I have already added some **string[]** into this class:
I'm new in java. Do you have a solution for my problem?

For example, I want to replace my string with `Table1` inside of this JSON:

```
public class JSON {
    public String jsonfile;

    public String JSONFilter(String[] point)throws IOException {
        String count01="{\n" +
                "  \"tags\": {\n" +
                "    \"load_all\": true,\n" +
                "    \"exclude\": [\n" +
                "      \"created_by\",\n" +
                "      \"source\"\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "  },\n" +
                "  \"tables\": {\n" +
                "    \"Table1\": {\n" +
                "      \"fields\": [\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"type\": \"id\",\n" +
                "          \"name\": \"osm_id\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"type\": \"geometry\",\n" +
                "          \"name\": \"geometry\"\n" +
                "        },\n" +
                "        {\n" +
                "          \"type\": \"hstore_tags\",\n" +
                "          \"name\": \"tags\"\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "      ],\n" +
                "      \"type\":";

        String count02 = "\"points\",\"mapping\":{";
        String count03 = "\"amenity\":[";
        for (int i=0; i<point.length; i++){
            String b1 = "\""+point[i].toString()+"\",";
            count03+=b1;
        }
        count03 = count03.replaceAll(",$", "");
        String count04= count03+"]";
        String count06= "}}}}";
        String part_final=count01+count02+count04+count06;
        System.out.println(part_final);

    }

}
```

Comment: have a look at this [jackson tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_quick_guide.htm) - *Step1  Create ObjectMapper object* *Step2 Serialize Object to JSON*

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but would simply changing `"    \"Table1\": {\n"` to `"    \""+otherClass.tableName()+"\": {\n"` cover your requirements? (You shouldn't really build JSON by hand, but that's a different issue.)